# MySql NOT EXIST or NOT IN with LIMIT on query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table "push_messages" with over 1,000,000 entries. I want MySql query that select the first 10 latest entries and check them against an array of id to select ENTRIES that IS NOT in the array.

```
 $array = array(5, 7, 2, 9);
 $sql ="SELECT id, name, message FROM push_messages
        WHERE id NOT IN (". implode(",", $array) .")
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 10";
```

but this does not return results in the first 10 list.

I will be glad if anyone can help me.. thank you.

Comment: Then what does it return?

Comment: it returns NO results... which means it does NOT return have ids that is NOT in the array.

Comment: I tried the query and it works fine

Comment: Please share the rest of your code (how you try to get the results, etc)

Comment: Yes i am run your query working ok

Comment: Every value from your implode must be in its own quotation marks Like `('7','6','8','9')`

Comment: your query perfectly working..!! please check the your code or please share the remaining code..!

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem this query, the problem elsewhere, you can share more of the code?

You can run, taking the output of the query.

```
SELECT id, name, message FROM push_messages
    WHERE id NOT IN (5,7,2,9)
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem that `NOT IN or IN work without "" in bracket ()` so you have remove "" from query like implode before query and store it in variable and pass string in query (in NOT IN bracket). 
I tried with your query it works fine,

you can try both

**Query without "" (qoutes)**,

> SELECT id, name, message FROM push_messages
>           WHERE id NOT IN (5, 7, 2, 9)
>           ORDER BY id DESC
>           LIMIT 10

It will returns all the results with ids 5,7,2,9.

**Query with "" (qoutes),**

> SELECT id, name, message FROM push_messages
>           WHERE id NOT IN ("5, 7, 2, 9")
>           ORDER BY id DESC
>           LIMIT 10

It will returns results with only id=5.

Comment: 2nd query will returns result with only id=5 i tried now and it's working